Get last item modified by user on SharePoint Site not knowing list
Is there a REST call I can use to get the last item modified by a specific user? This could take place on any list or library. I am familiar with the api lastitemusermodifieddate call but it doesn't return the list info. I'm trying to retrieve the list information for where it took place

Yes, there you go:
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$filter=Editor/Title eq 'UserName'&$orderby=Modified desc&$top=1&$select=Title,Modified,Editor/Title&$expand=Editor

Or if you are using email/UPN instead of DisplayName:
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$filter=Editor/Email eq 'john.doe@company.com'&$orderby=Modified desc&$top=1&$select=Title,Modified,Editor/Email&$expand=Editor


So I'm trying to get the list name. In your example, that call is using the listname, which I don't have. I'm looking for a way to pull in the last modified item, by the user, on the entire site. The ultimate goal is to get the listname, which I do not have.

Ah sorry, I missed that. I will try to find a better answer
